# Make gulp.dest output to same directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-dest

I have a structure like

- wwwroot/lib/site/scripts
- wwwroot/lib/site/scripts/modules
- wwwroot/lib/site/scripts/stuff

They all contain different js-files, I'd like to uglify them and output them to the same directory

The script below will only output them to

- wwwroot/scripts
- wwwroot/scripts/modules
- wwwroot/scripts/stuff

I'd like to have them all in wwwroot/scripts, I do not wish to concat any files.

```js
gulp.task('site-js', function () {
    var files = [
        'wwwroot/lib/site/scripts/**/*.js'
    ];

    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/scripts/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [`gulp-rename`](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename) is what you're looking for:

```
gulp.src('wwwroot/lib/site/scripts/**/*.js')
  .pipe(rename(path => { path.dirname = "" })) // remove relative path
  .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/scripts/'));
```